# Powering raspberry pi using VGA port of a display monitor

Tags: power-supply, usb-power

Does anyone have an idea if you could use the VGA port of a standard display monitor to power the raspberry pi? Obviously you would need a 'VGA to USB' adapter but then would it be possible

Comment: Apparently 5V 1A may be available. Might power a Pi Zero, but I wouldn't want to risk it. Why not use an official power supply? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "No" - as in [*"no way in hell"*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=no%20way%20in%20hell).

The graphics card in your PC supplies the 5V power between pins 9 & 5 on the **female** connector.

Don't forget to [vote for the correct answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers).